# Retrofit Android can't convert JSON response to model if the model's properties are private

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I tried using Retrofit on Android and I encountered this problem.
I want to get data in JSON from an API and convert it into a model in my app.

This is my model

```
public class A {
   private String property1;
   private int property2;

   //default constructor, getter and setter below
}
```

This is my service

```
public interface TestService {
   @GET("/a")
   void getA(Callback<A> callback);
}
```

When I retrieve the data using `TestService`, it won't return an error but it will return an empty class of `A`.
If I change the property of class `A` to `public`, then it will be converted to the right object `A`.

#### EDIT QUESTION

This is the JSON example that I want to convert into model `A`

```
{
   "property1" : "content",
   "property2" : 1
}
```

Comment: You could add @Expose annotation to your attributes, if you use GSON. I assume your getter/setters are public?

Comment: @Christopher I try to use `@Expose`, but it still doesn't work. Yeah all the getters and setters are public.

Comment: Just for clarification. Could you post your JSON as well?

Comment: I don't see any problems here. Maybe you can add the code, where you instantiate the Retrofit-Interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Expose annotation on your private fields if you are using GSON.

Like :

```
@Expose
private String property1;

@Expose
private int property2;
```

If you want to use a different name for your variables, you can try SerializedName annotation like :

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("property1")
private String p1;

@Expose
@SerializedName("property2")
private int p2;
```

I think that should work, if not post your complete "A" class.

Comment: it worked after I added the `@SerializedName` annotation. thanks @Abhilash